# Brighter method doesn't take effect for color

Tags: java, colors, awt

Why `Color.RED.brighter()` and `Color.RED` doesn't work or just dowsn't have any difference?
`darker()` method works perfect, but brighter gives the same color as without it.

Comment: Well, it doesn't get any brighter for `RED`. :-) Because `RED` is the _brightest_ in its case.

Comment: So why don't they set darker color for `RED` and one that is now on `RED` set for `brighter()`?

Comment: [`Color#RED`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#RED) is equivalent to `new Color(255,0,0)`. `255` is the maximum value that can be passed as a parameter. Hence, `RED` is _brightest_ (not lightest, there is a difference).